# saving uploaded files in selected directory

Tags: php, mysqli, image-upload

I'm building a multiple file uploader, using the  tutorial on this site, http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL.  And it works perfectly, however I would like to save the image as a url in SQL rather than just their names, and use the image name as a caption. Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_photos'])) {
include 'connect.php';
$album = (isset($_POST['album']) ? $_POST['album'] : null);
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['photos']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['photos']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['photos']['type'][$key]; 
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }
    include 'connect.php';      
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into album_images(imageURL, AlbumID) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $file_name,$album);
    $desired_dir="media/albums";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="media/albums/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }

       $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
```

}

HTML code

```
<form id="add-photos" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h5>Add Photos</h5>
    <div class="input-short" id="select_album">                 
    <?php select_album("SELECT * FROM album"); ?>
    </div>
    <label class="myLabel" id="upload-images">
    <input type="file" name="photos[]" id="fileToUpload"  multiple="multiple"/>
    <span>Select Photos</span>
    </label> 
    <button  id="facebook-image-submit" type="submit" name="add_photos">Add Photos</button>
 </form>
```

This code gives me the following  errors:

> Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\AfterGlowWebsite\CMS\functions.php on line: mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700); // Create directory if it does not exist#

Files are being added to SQL but not uploaded in the directory.

Comment: You have `$desired_dir` in quotes. Is this intended?

Comment: It was written like that on the tutorial, so I'm not sure if it is or not.

Comment: what is in `$desired_id` ?

Comment: There is no $desired_id, however my desired file path would be: media/albums/$file_name

Comment: Does the desire dir exists? $desired_dir="media/albums"; if you are using linux try /tmp/albums for example so you make sure apache has write permissions

Comment: The desired_dir does exist

Comment: The problem is that the files are not uploading in the directory even though the errors have been fixed;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.  Here is the solution:

```
/* upload photos to gallery */
if (isset($_POST['add_photos'])) {
include 'connect.php';
$album = (isset($_POST['album']) ? $_POST['album'] : null);
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['photos']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['photos']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['photos']['type'][$key]; 
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }
    include 'connect.php';
    $imageURL = "media/albums/".$file_name;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into album_images(imageURL, AlbumID) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $imageURL ,$album);
    $desired_dir="../media/albums";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);      // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir($desired_dir."/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../media/albums/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="media/albums/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
```

The probme was that I had written user_data rather than media/albums in  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../media/albums/".$file_name);
    }